# How to detect current display setting (i.e. extended, duplicate etc)

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# app that uses DisplaySwitch.exe to change the display setting to internal while it is running.

The issue is it needs to detect the computer's current setting before changing it so when the app is done it can restore it to the original setting.

I have found different examples on display settings for size, resolution etc., but not for whether the display is on internal monitor, external monitor, extended or duplicated.

I need to do this on all versions of Windows from XP to current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is impossible to do **explicitly** in C#. In other words, there is no call you can make that will return "Extended" or "Duplicate".

However, this status can be **inferred** if you know enough information about the target system. Since you care about duplicate/extend, we can assume that they are always on a multi-monitor setup. So, get the monitor count when you start:

```
Screen.AllScreens.Length
```

If it is 2 the answer is simple. The user must be in extended mode! If its 1, you are in one of the other 3 modes and need to decide which one you want to go back to. Duplicate seems like the most likely choice.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: To be honest that was not what we were looking for, but it actually led us to what we needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did it lead you to?

Comment: I cannot assume that the setup is always multi-monitor, but I see no harm in "restoring" to extend mode whether they have a second monitor or not.  The percentage of users that are in duplicate mode should be very minimal and is something we can handle.  Thanks again.